# Select month and date only

Tags: php

I have this column of a mysql table (DateOfBirth) in this format `02-03-2016`
I would like to display a message when member's date of birth is today. How can I select only the month and the date `02-03` in the column to compare it with `$dat=date("m-d");`. Behold my codes

```
 date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
 $dat=date("m-d");
 $resa=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT name FROM qbreplace.Staff_Member WHERE 
 DateOfBirth = '$dat'") or die ('Erreur : '.mysqli_error());
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resa)){
  echo "<div style='color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:blink;'>Today is ".$row['name']." birthday !</div>";
 }
```

Comment: It might be easier to pull the month, then use PHP to just pull out the days you need.

Comment: better use like condition there, dateOfBirth like '$date%', $date here is gmdate("m-d-");

Comment: your DB field is format of d-m-Y or m-d-Y?

Answer (score 1):

This should work although, there are so many elegant solutions. Also, as suggested by others verify whether the db stores date in  d-m-Y or m-d-Y format

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $dat=date("m-d");
    $resa=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT name FROM qbreplace.Staff_Member WHERE
     LEFT(DateOfBirth , 5) = '$dat'") or die ('Erreur : '.mysqli_error());

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resa)){
            echo "<div style='color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:blink;'>Today is ".$row['name']." birthday !</div>";

        }
```

The script checks for whether the first 5 characters in the DateOfBirth field is equal to the string you create in $dat.

A more elegant way would be do use the inbuilt date formatting, ie

```
 DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') = $dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
 $dat=date("m-d");
 $resa=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT name FROM qbreplace.Staff_Member WHERE 
 DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth,'%m-%d') = '$dat'") or die ('Erreur : '.mysqli_error());
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resa)){
echo "<div style='color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:blink;'>Today is ".$row['name']." birthday !</div>";

 }
```

you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to convert your date format temporarily and check the present date and month.
here goes your tutorial on `DATE_FORMAT`
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are some function are available in mysql to format your date so you can use those

You can use STR_TO_DATE() to convert your strings to MySQL date values or DATE_FORMAT function to convert your date into any format which you required

```
 STR_TO_DATE(datestring, '%d/%m/%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y')
```